# how can I add a wake up word using flutter speech recognition plugin

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition

I am using the Flutter speech recognition plugin and it works really well. However, it is constantly listening and I would prefer to have a wake word so that it only listens when I need it to.

At the moment it listens until there is a silence. Is there a way for me to shorten the length of time that it is listening? This way it can be listening to only one word at a time and waiting for whatever wake word I have set.

Comment: maybe create a variable that would be equal to several kinds of wake words. Then create something like if wake-word detected, then enter or continue.

Comment: Porcupine wake word recognition has a Flutter plugin :https://pub.dev/packages/porcupine

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wake word using the [porcupine](https://pub.dev/packages/porcupine) package.

First create your PorcupineManager:

```
 Future<void> createPorcupineManager() async {
try {
  porcupineManager = await PorcupineManager.fromKeywords(Porcupine.BUILT_IN_KEYWORDS, wakeWordCallback);
  } on PvError catch (err) {
    // handle porcupine init error
    print('Porcupine error: ' + err.message);
  }
}
```

Then start listening for wake words:

```
Future<void> listenForWakeWord() async {
try {
  await porcupineManager.start();
} on PvAudioException catch (ex) {
  // deal with either audio exception
  print('PvAudioException: ' + ex.message);
  }
}
```

The PorcuineManager comes with a decent list of built-in wake words which I've listed here:

- "alexa"
- "americano"
- "blueberry"
- "bumblebee"
- "computer"
- "grapefruit"
- "grasshopper"
- "hey google"
- "hey siri"
- "jarvis"
- "ok google"
- "picovoice"
- "porcupine"
- "terminator"